# search function in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

How to include  .php file in smarty, processing $_POST data from search input in Smarty and display results in .tpl file?
how to correctly define search.php in smarty controller or configuration file? i'm currently beginner  in smarty engine and don't know many things and tricks about this engine
***index.php smarty core***

```
<?php
//ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
$t1 = microtime ( 1 );
session_start ();
header ( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
require_once ("inc/initf.php");
//require_once("/verjani/public_html/inc/search.php");//how to include ?
$smarty = new Smarty ();
// $smarty->debugging = true;
// $smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
$smarty->cache_dir = THEM_PATH . "/cache";
$smarty->template_dir = THEM_PATH . "/template";
$smarty->compile_dir = THEM_PATH . "/template_c";
Helper::register($smarty);
$frontEnd = new frontEnd ();
$module = $frontEnd->getModule ();
$module->viewHeaders ();
if ($module->displayTpl !== false) {
    $smarty->assign ( 'COOKIE', $_COOKIE );
    $smarty->assign ( 'this', $module );
    $smarty->display ( $module->displayTpl, md5 ( $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
}
$t = microtime();
echo '<!--'.$t.'-->';
```

***search.php*** from http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#idp8696576

```
<?php 
  include('Smarty.class.php'); 

  $smarty = new Smarty; 

  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test'; 
  $login = 'test'; 
  $passwd = 'test'; 

  // setting PDO to use buffered queries in mysql is 
  // important if you plan on using multiple result cursors 
  // in the template. 

  $db = new PDO($dsn, $login, $passwd, array( 
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true)); 

  $res = $db->prepare("select * from users"); 
  $res->execute(); 
  $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY); 

  // assign to smarty 
  $smarty->assign('res',$res); 

  $smarty->display('index.tpl');?>
?>
```

***header.tpl.html***

```
<form method="post" action="../search.php" class="searchform cf">
              <input type="text" placeholder="">
              <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems the OP confusing Smarty with PHP. And search obviously have to be included in PHP, not smarty template

Comment: ok.how to correctly define search.php in smarty controller or configuration file? i'm currently beginner  in smarty engine and don't know many things and tricks about this engine

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers:

1. You don't have to create multiple instances of smarty, The only place smarty should be initialized is in your index.php file
2. Don't display your index.tpl file from your search.php file, the index.php file should include its own TPL file. Instead, have your search.php file access the database and return the results as an array and assigning  it to a smarty variable that you can use in your search to TPL file to display the results.

this is how I would do it.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
require('smarty-setup.php');

$smarty = new Smarty_Setup(); //must match class created in smarty setup file in order for it to work


require('search.php');

//uncomment these lines for debugging
// $smarty->debugging = true;
// $smarty->error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

**smarty-setup.php**

```
<?php

// load Smarty library
require('/smarty/Smarty.class.php');


// The setup.php file is a good place to load
// required application library files, and you
// can do that right here. An example:
// require('guestbook/guestbook.lib.php');

class Smarty_Setup extends Smarty {

   function __construct()

   {

        // Class Constructor.
        // These automatically get set with each new instance.
        parent::__construct();


        $this->setTemplateDir('/templates/');
        $this->setCompileDir('/smarty/templates_c/');
        $this->setConfigDir('/smarty/configs/');
        $this->setCacheDir('/smarty/cache/');
   }
}
?>
```

**Search.php**

```
  <?php

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['search'])))
  {

      $ResultsArray = array();
      //conduct your search using $_POST['search'] to get the search
      //query and put the results in the $ResultsArray above.

      $smarty->assign('searchResults', $ResultsArray);
      $smarty->assign('displayForm', 'false');
  } else {

      $smarty->assign('displayForm', 'true');
  }
  ?>
```

**Index.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        {include file='search.tpl'}
    </body>
</html>
```

**search.tpl**

```
{if $displayForm eq true}
    <form method="post" action="{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_NAME}" class="searchform cf">
          <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>

{else}

    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <ul>
        {foreach from=$searchResults item=result}
            <li>{$result}</li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
{/if}
```

here is some more info should you need it:

[Smarty if statements](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl)
[Smarty foreach statements](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)

Also, quick note. You can create a smarty-setup.php file where you can declare your config, templates, templates_C, and caches directories just as I did. See here (http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.extended.tpl) for a more detailed information on this.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
This search form is NOT secure in any way. It can be used to hack your site. In order to protect against such attacks please consult the following articles:

[Securing PHP forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)
[SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) (only necessary if you are querying a database).